# Fetching recent N records using Axios in react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, mongodb-atlas

How do you do it in Axios if you want to only fetch data of the last 10 posts, for example, and not all the data?
Again in such a way that when I click next or previous at the bottom of the page, the next 10 or previous 10 posts are fetched respectively.

Can you also reverse the order of the posts and how do u do it in Axios

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/posts/")
        
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                posts : res.data
            })
            

        })
        
    }

Comment: But this get all the data. Is there a way of quering only N records?

Comment: You will need to add pagination to your API to request items in a range

Comment: Can you illustrate or explain a little more to give me a good hint. Thanks man

Comment: I'm studying about pagination in react. Thank you for the hint

Comment: The idea is to implement the pagination in your API, not in React Component, then from your component you can request the items by page